# How to call parent component function on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call parent function on button click. I am not aware how to achieve this.

Parent component:

```
export default function Message({ component }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  const showMessage = ({ component }) => {
    setState(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {component}
      {state ? <div>Message</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now I am using this parent component:

```
import Message from "./message";

const EmbendComp = () => {
  const onClick = () => {
    alert("oooo");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Component</h1>
      <button onClick={onClick}>show Message</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Message component={<EmbendComp />} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I want to call `showMessage` function on button click. Is it possible? I want to "text" on button click.

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-gates-257xgw?file=/src/App.js:23-380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a callback function to `Message` which receives `onClick` and that `onClick` you can pass to `EmbedComp` and pass it as `args`:

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-moore-4crnkp?file=/src/App.js)

```
function Message({ component }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  const showMessage = () => {
    setState(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* CHANGE */}
      {component(showMessage)}
      {state ? <div>Message</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}

const EmbendComp = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Component</h1>
      {/* CHANGE */}
      <button onClick={onClick}>show Message</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* CHANGE */}
      <Message component={(onClick) => <EmbendComp onClick={onClick} />} />
    </>
  );
}
```

---

You can also pass whole component to `Message` and when you call it then you can pass the `onClick` as:

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-cherry-s4w2v7?file=/src/App.js)

```
function Message({ Component }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  const showMessage = () => {
    setState(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* CHANGE */}
      <Component onClick={showMessage} />
      {state ? <div>Message</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}

const EmbendComp = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Component</h1>
      {/* CHANGE */}
      <button onClick={onClick}>show Message</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* CHANGE */}
      <Message Component={EmbendComp} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing the parent component's params to `component`

```
import Message from "./message";

const EmbendComp = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Component</h1>
      <button onClick={onClick}>show Message</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Message component={(onMessageClick) => <EmbendComp onClick={onMessageClick} />} />
    </>
  );
}
```

And modify `Message` component like below

```
export default function Message({ component }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  const showMessage = ({ component }) => {
    setState(true);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {component(showMessage)}
      {state ? <div>Message</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can try this out in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-raman-3pxzjt?file=/src/App.js)